# XML Schema XSD understanding key/unique selector

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD, the aim is to have a unique name for the plc element. I expect the attached XML, which should not validate due to non-unique name. When I use "*" instead of "plc" for the selector xpath, everything is working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<piconfig xmlns="foobar.xsd">
    <plc name="foobar"/>
    <plc name="foobar"/>
</piconfig>
```

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="foobar" targetNamespace="foobar" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="piconfig">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="plc">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="UniquePlcName">
            <xs:selector xpath="plc"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSD.

The problems were because the namespace was not taken into account.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="foobar.xsd"
           xmlns:ns1="foobar.xsd">
    <xs:element name="piconfig">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ns1:plc"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="Unique_plc">
            <xs:selector xpath="ns1:plc"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="plc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. 

Why is it necessary to add the namespace? It was never used in the examples of the "XML Schema" book.

Comment: It's necessary because the XPath rules are that "no prefix means no namespace". I can't comment on the book - and there is more than one XML Schema book.